# Turn click function into Objects

Tags: jquery, function, object, jquery-isotope

I currently have an isotope and when I click on a button it brings up the following menus.  I have about twenty of these options.  I'd like to change them into objects so that I can reuse the code and make it much easier to maintain.  I am fairly new at object programming.  This is the code I have now that I want to change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn0").click(function(){
    $("#difficulty_plan_display").html("<br><h5 id='filter3-checker'>Cars Matching your Experience:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.model'>Models</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.stitch-and-glue'>Stitch and Glue</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.hybrid'>Hybrids</button><br><br><h5 id='filter4-checker'>Ways to Build:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.kit'>Complete Kits</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.part'>Wood Parts Only Kit</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.form'>Forms Kit</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.plan'>Plans &amp; Manual Only</button><br>");
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#difficulty_plan_display").html("<br><h5 id='filter3-checker'>Cars matching your Experience:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.model'>Models</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.stitch-and-glue'>Stitch and Glue</button><br><br><h5 id='filter4-checker'>Ways to Build:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.kit'>Complete Kits</button><br>");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#difficulty_plan_display").html("<br><h5 id='filter3-checker'>Cars Matching your Experience:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.model'>Models</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.stitch-and-glue'>Stitch and Glue</button><br><br><h5 id='filter4-checker'>Ways to Build:</h5><button class='button' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.kit'>Complete Kits</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.part'>Wood Parts Only Kit</button><br>");
  });

  $("#cartype_btn0").click(function(){
    $("#specific_car_filters_display").html("<br><h3>For All Cars</h3><h5 id='filter5-checker'>Anticipated Use?</h5><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='*'>show all</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.light-touring'>Touring</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.sailing'>Racing</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.show'>Showing</button><br>");
  });
  $("#cartype_btn1").click(function(){
    $("#specific_car_filters_display").html("<br><h3>For Convertibles</h3><h5 id='filter5-checker'>Anticipated Use?</h5><button class='button is-checked' data-filter-value='.convertible'>show all</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.convertible.recreational'>Recreational</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.convertible.performance'>Performance</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.convertible.touring'>Touring</button><button class='button' data-filter-value='.convertible.sedan'>Sedan</button><br>");
  });
```

Here is one of the divs that calls some of the above code:

```
<div id="filters-two" class="button-group">
    <button id="btn0" class="button is-checked" value="0" data-filter-value="*">show all</button>
    <button id="btn1" class="button" value="1" data-filter-value=".none">None</button>
</div>
```

And this is my rebuilding of the page based upon button clicks:

```
/******** REBUILD COMBO FILTER FUNCTION *********/
    function rebuildComboFilter(filterType, filterValue) {
        var newFilterArray = [];
        var newFilterString = '';
        storedComboFilterObject[filterType] = filterValue;
        for (var type in storedComboFilterObject) {
            if (storedComboFilterObject[type] === '*' && _.contains(newFilterArray, '*')) {
                // do nothing: * already present, do not add another * to filters
            } else {
                newFilterArray.push(storedComboFilterObject[type]);
            }
        }

        // sort filters to push a possible * ahead of defined classes
        newFilterArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a === "*") ? -1 : 1;
        });

        newFilterString = newFilterArray.join('');
        storedFilterString = newFilterString;
        $('#filterstringmonitor').val(storedFilterString);
        $container.isotope({ filter: storedFilterString });
    }
    /******** END REBUILD COMBO FILTER FUNCTION *********/


    // respond to click in button-group and rebuild combo filters - check filterSelectors object
    $('.button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter-value');
        if (filterSelectors[filterValue]) {
            filterValue = filterSelectors[filterValue];
        } else {
            filterValue = filterValue;
        }
        rebuildComboFilter($(this).parent('.button-group').attr('id'), filterValue);
    });
```

I looked online for solutions and found one reference:

```
<p><a id="link" href="#">click me</a></p>

<script>
var link = document.getElementById("link");
AttachEvent(link, "click", EventHandler);

function AttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
}

function EventHandler(e) {
    console.log(this);
}
</script>


All browsers set ‘this’ to the element which fired the event … except one. Internet Explorer 8.0 and below only reference the event handler so ‘this’ is always the global window object.

Fortunately we can determine the target element from the event object instead:


function EventHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log(target);
}
```

But I am definitely lost as to whether this is what I am looking for.   And if it is, I have no idea as to what the eventHandler, type, and elements would be as it relates to my code.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#btn0")` is an object. If you want set of button objects inside filter divs, you can use

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-group button");
```

to add them a common click handler, you can use

```
function buttonHandler(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if(target.id=="btn0") ... // do whatever you want
}

for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) buttons[i].click = buttonHandler;
```